# How to load c# ascx user control based on condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I am converting an aspx website from separate aspx language pages (utilizing the same code behind) to one main aspx with user controls. I have one user control ascx file for each language, all with the same IDs in them so the same code behind can be used for any of them. How can I conditionalize which one gets displayed to the user without running into compile issues?

use session variable Session["lang"]
This is what I have:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="section" TagName="account"      Src="account.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="section" TagName="account_span" Src="account_span.ascx" %>
```

EDIT: Solution
This is what I ended up using in the .aspx

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder_section" runat="server" />
```

and what I have in the code-behind: section variable hold each section name and suffix is the language

```
 PlaceHolder_section.Controls.Add(this.LoadControl(section + suffix + ".ascx"));
```

Comment: Can you share some code please? Can't you use localization to make language dependent pages?

Comment: There is no need to use the word "this" on this.LoadControl....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)-method to load a UserControl dynamically. See this [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details.
So in your case, you would have code like this in the CodeBehind (Page Init or Load) of your page:

```
MyUserControlType ctrl;
if (Session["lang"] == "en-US") 
    ctrl = (MyUserControl) LoadControl("~/PathToUserControl/eng.ascx");
else if (Session["lang"] == "es-ES")
    ctrl = (MyUserControl) LoadControl("~/PathToUserControl/span.ascx");
else 
    ctrl = null;
if (ctrl != null)
{
    // Initialize properties of ctrl
    Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

Instead of having a long list of ifs or a switch statement, you could name your UserControls after a certain pattern and store a suffix in the session:

```
string userCtrlSuffix = ((string) Session["UserControlSuffix"]) ?? "Eng";
MyUserControlType ctrl = (MyUserControl) LoadControl("~/PathToUserControl/UserControl" + userCtrlSuffix + ".ascx");
// Initialize properties of ctrl
Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

As @samy mentioned in the comments, loading controls dynamically needs to happen early in the page lifecycle in order to handle ViewState correctly and hook up event handlers properly.

Comment: Be aware that there are very specific moments when you want to load a control dynamically since viewstate data may not load for it if the lifecycle of the page is too advanced: as a rule, try loading your control at the soonest moment possible (Init is a good moment, fwiw)